# How to get access to my old blog( Over 9 years) on WordPress- forget the login details

Tags: wordpress

I am a food blogger, I have an old blog that I do not have access to, I do not remember the login details and email I subscribed to the above blog.
I turned to WordPress to help me but they ask for permission to purchase plugins, to verify that it's me but I did not purchase any plugins and even if I purchased I can not remember because it is very old, over 9 years
I even sent them a photo of my ID to verify that this is my blog but they refuse to verify this way
What can I do beyond hacking into my blog?

Comment: Login to your hosting and check the wp_users table - you will be able to check/change the email.

Comment: didn't  understand  what  you are trying  to  explAIN

Comment: I did not understand what you wrote down ..what should I do?

Comment: Login to my hosting ?

Comment: Each website is hosted somewhere. You most likely pay for it. If you log in to the hosting control panel you will be able to log in to the database and there you will be able to check the wp_users table which contains your account details. You won't be able to check the password but you will be able to check/change the email address.

Comment: I contacted a company that hosts my old site, Automattic but my referral comes straight to WordPress for some reason ... and they are not willing to tell me what one email I signed up for

Comment: I contacted a company that hosts my old site, "Automattic", but my referral comes straight to WordPress for some reason ... and they are not willing to tell me what one email I signed up for

Comment: If you don't have access to the hosting then there is nothing you can do...

Comment: There must be a way, it does not make sense that there is no solution, I have a photo ID to send? What better way than this to locate my site?

Comment: Where is your site hosted?  What does `my referral comes straight to WordPress` mean?

Comment: You can start by sending a link to your blog. Is it self hosted (e.g. did you pay for hosting during this 9yr period?) or is it a wordpress.com website?